# Check if the next item is 1 unit longer (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a coding **beginner** and I was writing the following function that checks if the next string of a given array is **one unit longer**:

```
function canBuild(arr) {
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i == arr.length-1) { return true }
        if (arr[i].length+1 != arr[i+1].length) { return false }
    }
}
```

**desired output**:

`canBuild(["a", "at", "ate", "late", "plate", "plates"]) ➞ true`

`canBuild(["it", "bit", "bite", "biters"]) ➞ false`

// "biters" is 2 units longer than the previous string

I was wondering if there is a more efficient and shorter way to write the same function, if someone explained me other ways to do so I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Can you please add an example and a desired output ? Thanks

Comment: The first `if` can be part of the `for` header (and then move the `return true` after the loop): `for (let i = 0; i < (arr.length - 1); i++) { ... }`

Comment: Please elaborate what use case you are trying to achieve. At high level define your input and expected output so people here can understand the problem and the goal.

Comment: It's as efficient as it can be. You have to check every element (in the worst case) in the array and there's no shorter way for the comparison. And "shorter" is not always better. Write code you understand by just looking at it. Anything else will only make the maintenance harder.

Comment: Efficiency is a very vague term in computing, it could mean different things in different scenarios. If you are chasing increased throughput, I'd suggest properly analysing your code before blindly applying premature optimisations.

Comment: Can you confirm that you expect `true` to be returned if the array has less that 2 elements? (that's what you code currently does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `every` method and some temp variable (`x` here)

```js
const canBuild = (arr) => (
  (x = arr[0]?.length), arr.every((c) => c.length === x++)
);

console.log(canBuild(["a", "at", "ate", "late", "plate", "plates"]));

console.log(canBuild(["it", "bit", "bite", "biters"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function canBuild(arr) {
        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(i+1 != arr[i].length)
               return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This is a O(n) solution.

Comment: This only works if the first element of the array has a length of 1. It will fail for `canBuild(["at", "ate", "late", "plate", "plates"])`

Comment: Thanks improving the answer!

Comment: I didn't improve your answer... I just pointed out a shortcoming. The improving is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
   function canBuild(arr) {
        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(i > 0 && arr[i].length !== arr[i-1].length+1)
               return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

EDIT: even better, as suggeste by Thomas:

```
     function canBuild(arr) {
        for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i].length !== arr[i-1].length+1)
               return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: How is this more "efficient" or "shorter"?

Comment: if you `let i=1` then you don't need to test `i>0 &&`

Comment: @Andreas if gets rid of the `i == arr.length-1` test each loop turn, which is good. But on the contrary it adds `i > 0`, which is bad..